# Web scraping usando o rvest

Tags: r

Estou tentando extrair os dados de um site (onde é necessário fazer login) mas não estou conseguindo.

```
html_nodes("https://www.comdinheiro.com.br/home3/","div th")
```

A saída não está condizente com o código fonte. Não está mostrando as cotações dos ativos que estão na página. 
É possível que esteja dando esse problema pois é necessário fazer o login no site com o script (a url que estou usando já esta dentro da área logada)?

Comment: Você verificou se existe uma tag table no código fonte da página? Veja se a solução para essa pergunta te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/428240/baixar-dados-de-tabelas-da-bolsa-de-valores-no-r