# Baixar dados de tabelas da Bolsa de Valores no R

Tags: r, aplicação-web, web-scraping, rvest

Tenho o seguinte código, necessito baixar os dados que estão na tabela, mas o dataframe está retornando sempre vazio.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(bizdays)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#### Carregar dados ####

url <- 'http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/consultas/mercado-de-derivativos/precos-referenciais/taxas-referenciais-bm-fbovespa/'

html <- read_html(url) 

dados <- html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//table//td") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_replace(",", ".") %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Estou achando que o site da B3 não permite que se baixe diretamente via webscrap. Tentei de várias formas (inclusive com o pacote "rvest") e sempre retorna vazio. Recomendo explorar e tentar baixar informações relativas à B3 pelo pacote "BatchGetSymbols". Ou copiar a tabela para o Excel e fazer a leitura pelo R.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas!

Comment: @AlexandreSanches considere editar o título da pergunta para torná-la mais geral. Seu problema não se limita ao site da bolsa, isso ocorre em diversas URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É fácil notar que não há erro algum no seu código. Pare ver isso, basta substituir sua url por uma url que tenha uma tabela bem formatada. Uso aqui como exemplo esse [site](http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47401&view=1). Veja:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(bizdays)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


japan<- "http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47401&view=1"
html <- read_html(japan) 

dados_japan <- html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//table//td") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_replace(",", ".") %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  matrix(ncol = 14, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% setNames(c('Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',
                                 'May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep',
                                 'Oct','Nov','Dec','Annual'))

head(dados_japan)
```

Output:

```
  Year Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May Jun Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec Annual
1   NA  NA 1938 -5.2 -4.9 -0.6 4.7 9.5 11.6 17.9 22.2 16.5 10.7    3.3
2 -4.7 6.8 1939 -7.5 -6.6 -1.4 4.0 7.5 13.0 17.4 20.0 17.4  9.7    3.0
3 -2.5 6.2 1940 -6.0 -5.7 -0.5 3.5 8.5 11.0 16.6 19.7 15.6 10.4    3.7
4 -1.0 6.3 1941 -6.5 -5.8 -2.6 3.6 8.1 11.4 12.7 16.5 16.0 10.0    4.0
5 -2.9 5.4 1942 -7.8 -8.2 -0.8 3.5 7.1 12.0 17.4 18.4 15.7 10.5    2.5
6 -2.9 5.6 1943 -4.1 -6.1 -1.1 3.5 6.9 12.9 19.3 21.5 17.5 11.7    1.2
```

Se o código está certo, por que a falha em realizar o mesmo procedimento no site da Bovespa? Creio que isso se deve à formatação no código fonte da página. Note que se você abrir o código fonte da página da Agência Japonesa de Metereologia utilizada no exemplo (Crtl+U no google chrome ou BD->View page source), clicar Ctrl+F e procurar o termo "table" você vai perceber que o conteúdo da tabela de interesse encontra-se envolto em uma *tag* "table class". No entanto, quando você realiza o mesmo procedimento na página da Ibovespa não existe uma *tag* equivalente. Por trás das cenas creio que a funçao `read_html` procura essa *tag* de tabela, se ela não encontra, a busca retorna vazia e o código falha.

**O que fazer?**

Bom, nesse caso você vai precisar encontrar manualmente a tabela e só então usar a função `read_html` com os inputs corretos de URL e `xpath`. Para isso basta seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Clique com o BD em cima da tabela
2. View frame source
3. Ctrl+F "table". Ela estará lá
4. Copie a url (sem o "view-source:") e substitua no seu código
5. Volte na página original
6. Pegue o `xpath` da tabela (BD->Inspect, seleciona elemento,
   BD->copy->xpath)
7. Coloque esse `xpath` no argumento de `html_nodes`

O código ficará assim:

```
bovespa <- 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp'
html <- read_html(bovespa) 

dados_bov <- html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="tb_principal1"]')%>% #aqui você já tem a tabela, daqui para baixo o código apenas padroniza a tabela que vem desestruturada
  html_text()%>%
  str_replace(",", ".") %>%
  str_replace_all('(\r|\n){1,}',';')%>%


dados_bov=strsplit(dados_bov,';')[[1]][5:892]%>% #transforma a string em uma lista e elimina o cabeçalho da base
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)%>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  setNames(c("Dias Coriidos", "DI_pre_252", "DI_pre_360"))

head(dados_bov)
```

Output:

```
  Dias Coriidos DI_pre_252 DI_pre_360
1             3       4.15       0,00
2             7       4,01       4,10
3            10       4,01       3,43
4            12       4,00       3,81
5            13       4,00       3,95
6            14       4,00       4,08
```

> **BD:** botão direito

Comment: Muito obrigado pela excelente explicação!

Answer (score 1):

As páginas do domínio da B3 utilizam iframes para se referenciar aos dados que ainda estão no servidor com o domínio BVMF.

Basta abrir o Inspector (F12) e realizar uma busca por 'iframe'. Existe um iframe com id 'bvmf_iframe' onde estará o link para a página que é usada como origem para a tabela presente no domínio b3.com.br.

No seu caso específico, esta é a página:

http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp